# Displaying The System's Output Volume Numerically in Applescript on a Mac

Tags: macos, variables, applescript, system, volume

I have a simple little Applescript that I wrote a few months back which I've named MiniVolume and given a dock icon for easy access. It works like so: the user opens the application, and it asks what they would like to change the output volume to. The user then inputs a numerical value, presses submit, and the system's output volume is changed to the number that the user input.

There's one little feature I've wanted to implement for a while now, and have left a space to do so: displaying the current output volume as a numeric value. Doing so would be invaluable to me, as it would help me gauge just how much I need to change the number when setting my volume to fractions of a notch.

Here's the AppleScript (short enough to go here in one piece, I suppose. Let me know if the case is otherwise by the rules of StackOverflow):

```
set dialogText to "MiniVolume" & "
" & "
" & "Current volume:" & "
" & "Set the volume to:"
display dialog dialogText default answer ""
set newVolume to text returned of result
set volume output volume newVolume
```

Where you see `"Current volume:"` is where I'd like to implement the variable into the text. I've tried to go about doing this by saying something like

```
" & "Current volume:" & output volume & "
```

or

```
" & "Current volume:" & volume & "
```

but neither has worked. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this works is a little weird. There's a `get volume settings` command, whose result is a record of class `volume settings`, which has a property `output volume`.

I say it's weird because this works:

```
get volume settings -- result: {output volume:25, input volume:50, alert volume:83, output muted:false}
```

And I was tempted to do:

```
get output volume of volume settings -- fails to compile
```

The reason that doesn't work is that `get volume settings` is not a `get` command followed by `volume settings` as the thing to get. It's an indivisible command phrase.

Anyway, the right approach is:

```
get output volume of (get volume settings) -- result: 25
```

So, anyway, you can just use this line in your code:

```
" & "Current volume:" & output volume of (get volume settings) & "
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much. Works like a charm. Also a very thorough explanation of the concepts behind it. Much appreciated!